# How to examine value inside c# predicate parameter? - Determining predicate equality

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-4.0

I'm trying to determine the equality of two predicates:

```
public T FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (EntityCache.ContainsKey(predicate.GetHashCode()))
        return EntityCache[predicate.GetHashCode()];
    else
    {
        var entity = _objectSet.FirstOrDefault<T>(predicate);
        EntityCache.Add(predicate.GetHashCode(), entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is the hash code of the predicate doesn't account for the values used inside it, and I'm not sure how to go about retrieving them.

If for instance the predicate passed to our method above is: (r => r.Id == id) how would I go about finding the value of 'id' inside my FirstOrDefault method?

Comment: Why do you want to?  The whole point of a syntax where you take in a `Func<T, bool>` is that you have no idea how it's implemented.  It's not up to you as the *implementor* of `FirstOrDefault` to know how the *user* of your method chooses to filter the results.  They *may* choose to use the `Id` property, or they might have some completely different predicate.   For what it's worth, you could convert it to take a `Func<T, int>` and assume they are returning the pk and then you can invoke the predicate to get the value for the current instance of `T`.

Comment: I guess the answer then is there's no easy way to do this, since I'd like to keep the flexibility of passing any predicate and somehow being able to determine if that predicate and value set is the same as one that was passed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use Expression's. They contains func's, but they also contain the syntax tree and you can examine their 'source code' at runtime.

Comment: However, I have to admit that this way of doing things still stinks, you shouldn't cache predicates either. Create your own class which encapsulates a field name and a field value, for example. Like new QueryFilter("Id", 12). This will lead to a much better design.

Comment: The thing is though I'd like to keep the flexibility of being able to pass any predicate I want to the method, I simply want to somehow determine if that predicate and it's parameter value set was passed before.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't limit you in any way, you can create any set of filter expression derivatives. Create an abstract filter base class with type param <T>, which has a single method, bool DoesItMatch(T elem). Then derive a SimpleFilterExpression<T> that takes a property name and value as a constructor parameter. Then feel free to add any other derived classes. Then make sure that all classes provide GetHashCode and Equals which will be very simple because you have these simple implementation classes.

Comment: The main problem is that if you use even a simple "x => x.Id == 12" expression in 2 different places, the compiler will compile it as 2 different functions. Comparing code or expressions will be very difficult. For example "y => 12 == y.Id" does the same but it's already a different code. It's a nightmare. So, for the simple cases, use my suggestions and encapsulate the filter logic in classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to determine the value of a captured variable inside a delegate. I'm pretty sure there's no easy way to do this... perhaps if you used an expression tree instead of a delegate it would be simpler ?
Another option (probably much simpler) is keeping the values passed to the delegates alongside them in `EntityCache`

Also note that instead of

```
if (EntityCache.ContainsKey(predicate.GetHashCode()))
    return EntityCache[predicate.GetHashCode()];
```

It would be better to use `TryGetValue`

Comment: Thanks for the TryGetValue tip, will use that.

Comment: NONONONO, -1. Don't EVER assume that two objects are equal because their hash codes are (pigeonhole principle)

Comment: @erikkallen you're absolutely right (I didn't even notice he was using the hashcodes) - but what does it have to do with my answer ? I was merely pointing out the the `if contains return []` pattern is better implemented with the `TryGetValue` method - And even that was an aside to the essence of my answer...